# C# WinForms - Преобразование json в "понятный для пользователя" текст

Tags: c#, json, winforms, vkontakte-api

Я учусь VK Api. При реализации GET Запроса, возникла проблема: Текст выводится в формате json, а мне нужно вывести его в "понятный" для пользователя текст. Как это можно сделать? Желательно примеры для моего кода:

```
var client = new WebClient();
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=210700286&fields=bdate&v=5.64"))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            textBox1.Text = text;
        }
```

Comment: Парсите JSON через [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: @Alex78191 Я так и не понимал как это делать... По этому и попросил примеры для кода

Comment: Это не видели? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483006/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-json-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-json-net https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/260058/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-json-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-json-net

Comment: @Alex78191 Всё ровно не понимаю - где брать текст который "парсить" нужно?

Comment: Он в переменной text.

Comment: @Alex78191 Вот я я дурак! Спасибо!

Comment: @Alex78191 Всё получилось и работает! Спасибо вам! Сколько времени я не мог понять где именно взять текст для парсинга.. Но у меня еще появился вопрос: В примерах в ручную вписывается этот текст, а возможно вывести текст уже готовый? То есть: В "text" есть все нужные значения, возможно ли сделать тоже самое, не писав их в ручную?

Comment: сколько часов?  Рекомендую изучить HTTP

Comment: в смысле готовый? Вы и текст Без пирсинга выводите.

Comment: Ну я создал отдельную "string", где поместил все, что было в text, и далее это обработал. Можно как-то обойтись без "string", и сразу работать с text

Comment: @Alex78191 могу код скинуть

Comment: дополните вопрос

Comment: @Alex78191 Ну вот допустим: Я создал класс, в который поместил переменные: 'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'bdate'. Далее происходит запрос, и у меня получается переменная 'text', где содержится текст в формате json. В моём варианте: я создавал еще переменную, куда вписывал этот json текст, и дальше делал "Deserialize an Object"(прочитал на json.net). Вопрос: Возможно повторить тоже самое, но: без создавания переменной(Ведь нужный текст вроде есть в 'text'?).

Comment: @Alex78191 Вот скрин кода: http://imgur.com/a/d6Vf7 . Вопрос: можно сделать тоже самое, без 'json1'?

Comment: я же сказал использовать переменную text. Text сразу и подавай в метод. Вы вообще понимаете как как методы с параметрами работают?

Comment: @Alex78191 Видимо я еще и слоупок... Спасибо=)

Comment: Нормальные люди используют библиотеку VkNet.